# linux-image-5.8.0-7630-generic

Tags: linux, terminal, kernel, pop-os

After the upgrade, this happens for Linux and gives an error.
Every code I type in the terminal gives the same error.
I tried these three ways but it didn't work.

```
sudo apt install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt autoremove -f -y
```

ERROR :

```
Reading package lists... Done\
Building dependency tree\
Reading state information... Done\
Calculating upgrade... Done\
The following packages will be REMOVED:\
  linux-image-5.8.0-7630-generic\
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.\
4 not fully installed or removed.\
After this operation, 13.9 MB disk space will be freed.\
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y\
(Reading database ... 259993 files and directories currently installed.)\
Removing linux-image-5.8.0-7630-generic (5.8.0-7630.32~1609174078~20.04~4b8d17c) ...\
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:\
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-7630-generic\
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:\
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'\
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'\
Generating grub configuration file ...\
Script `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new' contains no commands and will do nothing\
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.\
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub\
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with\
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.\
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1\
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.8.0-7630-generic (--remove):\
 installed linux-image-5.8.0-7630-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1\
dpkg: too many errors, stopping\
Errors were encountered while processing:\
 linux-image-5.8.0-7630-generic\
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.\
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

[image]

but there was no file in /etc/grub.d.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you `Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.` as the above asks?

Comment: I edited the question but there was no file in /etc/grub.d.

Comment: The files in `/etc/grub.d` come from the `grub-common` package.  You could try to reinstall it.  By the way, pasting text is preferred to images as it allows search engines to find it (so your problems are shared) and allows others to copy/paste if needed.